# How to get miniature (live thumbnail preview) of open windows on Linux?

Tags: linux, gnome, graphics, window

Gnome-shell does it in the 'activities' screen, unity/compiz has it in 'Spread','Shift','ALT-Tab'.

How do I get those live window previews in C++?